# Easiest way to receive Office 365 email from C# Windows service?

Tags: azure, office365

My program needs to read and delete emails from an email account on Office 365. I was using Mailkit but it failed when calling Authenticate either from Pop or Imap. I learned that Office 365 disabled legacy username/password authentication. When I tried to use OAuth2, I hit a road block. I can't use delegated permission because my program is a non-interactive service. I can't use app permission either because I can't get permission from the domain admin. I've been working for days on the "supposed-to-be-simple" task without success. Anyone can help?

Answer (score 0):

One of the workaround is to utilise [Microsoft graph](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/overview-major-services) which allows you to leverage REST APIs and client libraries to interface with Microsoft 365, Windows 10, and Enterprise Mobility and Security services in Microsoft 365. Microsoft Graph allows you to access data with the right permissions.

Depending on your scenario, You can use [Daemon tools](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/scenario-daemon-overview)  which uses [Client Credentials](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/sdks/choose-authentication-providers?tabs=CS#client-credentials-provider) flow which enables service applications to run without user interaction.